# JAX-WS SOAP return type

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am trying to use File as a return type for JAX-WS but its giving compile time error as **"Class java.io.File may not be used as a return type or method parameter as it has inner types that are not public and static**".
Though error itself clarifies things but I would like to know if there are any other alternative of sending file as attachment with different return type.I think i can return in bytes[] & MTOM also but would like to get few more suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SOAP I think you have limited options. You can try these classes once:
`javax.activation.FileDataSource;`
`javax.activation.DataHandler;`
and give the proper MIME type